# How to use Modal Form into loop in Razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I used the modal form to send a user value And I put a form inside the modal and put the modal in a loop to get the value of the selected user ID and send. When I enter the model id value in the form, the correct value is not sent and one less number is sent.
The correct id value is sent without using the Form.

Please tell me where the problem is and how I can solve it.

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.ProjectViewModels)
            {


                <tr>
                    <td>@item.PersonName @item.Family</td>
                    <td>@item.PersonCode</td>

                    <td>@item.projectName</td>

                                <div>
                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="detailsPerson" asp-route-id="@item.PersonID">جزئیات</a>

                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" asp-controller="Report" asp-action="SingelGhrardad" asp-route-id="@item.PersonID">قرارداد</a>

                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ترک کار</a>
                                    <!-- The Modal -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog ">
                                            <div class="modal-content">

                                                <!-- Modal Header -->
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title">ثبت تاریخ ترک کار پرسنل</h4>

                                                </div>

                                                <!-- Modal body -->
                                                <div class="modal-body">

                                                    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="PersonTarkKar"  asp-route-PersonNewState="0" method="post">


                                                        <div class="row">

                                                            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                                                                <label>تاریخ ترک کار</label>

                                                                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                                                                    <div class="input-group-addon"
                                                                         style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                                                                        <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <input id="calender1" name="calender1" type="text" required autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                                                                    <input  name="id" value="@item.PersonID" class="form-control d-none" />

                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>


                                                        <button class="btn btn-dark mt-5" type="submit">ثبت تاریخ</button>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>

                                                <!-- Modal footer -->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        }



                    </td>

                </tr>

            }

public IActionResult PersonTarkKar(int id ,int PersonNewState,String calender1 )
{
    var per = _context.Persons.Find(id);

    per.PersonState = PersonNewState;
    per.PersonTarkKarDate = calender1;

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("allPerson");
}
```

[image]

Comment: plls show PersonTarkKar action.

Comment: The problem with the for loop could not be solved.My problem is that when I put the Form inside the loop, the value of @ item.PersonID that it sends is not correct

Comment: I edited the question, please check.I used Form to send information in Modal Diloge. But PersonID will not be sent correctly if it is sent in the form

Comment: Thanks. I would like to see Model, and  ProjectViewModels classes

Comment: Can you clarify `When I enter the model id value in the form, the correct value is not sent and one less number is sent. The correct id value is sent without using the Form.`?I test with the code,it can post id,calender1 and PersonNewState to PersonTarkKar correctly.

Comment: Yes, it works well if it has one record, but if you have several records, the value @ item.PersonID does not work properly, because the form is inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal id is not unique,so when you click button,it will open the same modal,so the hidden input will be the same one.Try to make your modal id unique,so that it will open the right modal each time.

```
@{ var count = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.ProjectViewModels)
            {


                <tr>
                    <td>@item.PersonName @item.Family</td>
                    <td>@item.PersonCode</td>

                    <td>@item.projectName</td>

                                <div>
                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="detailsPerson" asp-route-id="@item.PersonID">جزئیات</a>

                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" asp-controller="Report" asp-action="SingelGhrardad" asp-route-id="@item.PersonID">قرارداد</a>

                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal@(count)">ترک کار</a>
                                    <!-- The Modal -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal@(count)">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog ">
                                            <div class="modal-content">

                                                <!-- Modal Header -->
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title">ثبت تاریخ ترک کار پرسنل</h4>

                                                </div>

                                                <!-- Modal body -->
                                                <div class="modal-body">

                                                    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="PersonTarkKar"  asp-route-PersonNewState="0" method="post">


                                                        <div class="row">

                                                            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                                                                <label>تاریخ ترک کار</label>

                                                                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                                                                    <div class="input-group-addon"
                                                                         style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                                                                        <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <input id="calender1" name="calender1" type="text" required autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                                                                    <input  name="id" value="@item.PersonID" class="form-control d-none" />

                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>


                                                        <button class="btn btn-dark mt-5" type="submit">ثبت تاریخ</button>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>

                                                <!-- Modal footer -->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @{count++;}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        }



                    </td>

                </tr>

            }
```

**Update:**
If you use `calender1@ (count)`,try to do like this:

```
$(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i <@(count); i++) {
                $('#calender1' + i).MdPersianDateTimePicker({ targetTextSelector: '#calender1' + i, });
            }
            
        })
```

Comment: Your code works fine but I have a calender (DateTimePicker) in the form which now only shows in the first record id I set it to calender1@ (count) but it did not work

Comment: <script>
        $('#calender1@(count)').MdPersianDateTimePicker({
            targetTextSelector: '#calender1@(count)',
        });
    </script>

Comment: <input id="calender1@(count)" name="calender1" type="text"  />

Comment: I have updated my answer,the id is unique,so `$('#calender1@(count)').MdPersianDateTimePicker({ targetTextSelector: '#calender1@(count)', ` will only change one input.

Answer (score 0):

replace foreach loop by for loop

```
 @for (var i=0; i< Model.ProjectViewModels; i++)
{
 <td>@Model.ProjectViewModels[i].PersonName @item.Family</td>
 <td>@Model.ProjectViewModels[i].PersonCode</td>

 <td>@Model.ProjectViewModels[i].projectName</td>
.....

<input  name="id" value="@Model.ProjectViewModels[i].PersonID" class="form-control d-none" />
....
}
```